# Why is it forbidden to qualify name in extern declaration?

Tags: c++, namespaces, extern

Why are names introduced by an extern declaration only allowed to come from the innermost enclosing namespace? What complication would it draw in, if they weren't? Or is it just because this part of standard was copied from C standard, where no namespace take place?

[Please see the respective part of the standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.link#8)

EDIT:
An example scenario where qualification would be handy: a use of `x` in the  function template `f` in namespace `ns`, where `x` is defined somewhere in the global namespace and is not desirable to be introduced (outside the function definition) in all translation units that *#include* the header with `f`.

```
namespace ns
{
  template <typename> void f()
  {
    // extern int ::x; // ill-formed
    extern int x;      // refers to ns::x, which is not the case :(
    ++x;
  }
}
```

Comment: The quoted passage says nothing about qualifying any names. It only says when two declarations declare the same entity.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.: _ignoring entities declared outside the innermost enclosing namespace scope_; this (incomplete) statement clearly bans linkage to any name outside said namespace using this declaration. maybe the qualification itself is explicitly disallowed somewhere else in the standard - I don't know. but maybe it is implied by this rule solely.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it forbidden to qualify name in extern declaration?

Because it makes no sense.

Suppose you want to use `foo::bar` while being in namespace `foo:::baz`. There are two cases

1. The declaration of `foo::bar` is visible. Then you don't need to redeclare it. Just use the name, qualified if need be.
2. The declaration of `foo::bar` is not visible. Then you cannot first declare it in any namespace other than `foo`.

> Why are names introduced by an extern declaration only allowed to come from the innermost enclosing namespace?

They are not. They may come from the global namespace, which is the primary use case for `extern`. The other use case is forward-declaring a function that will be defined later in the same namespace, which is I suppose the only reason why such same-namespace declarations are even allowed. There isn't much need for `extern` outside of these use cases. Forward-declaring `foo::bar` from inside `foo::baz` is too confusing and error prone.

Comment: would you kindly look at the example I added to my question? it introduces a use case you haven't covered in your answer. thank you

Comment: Don't know, perhaps the standard wants to discourage you from using globals.